# Autofac custom configuration in C#

Tags: c#, autofac

I have 3 classes Class1, 2 and 3 and a class Manage

```
public class Class1
{
  public void PrintMessageForClass1()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This is class1");
  }
}


public class Class2
{
  public void PrintMessageForClass2()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This is class2");
  }
}

public class Class3
{
  public void PrintMessageForClass3()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("This is class3");
  }
}


public class Manage
{
  Class1 c1;
  Class2 c2;
  Class3 c3;

  public Manage (Class1 c1, Class2 c2 ,Class3 c3)
  {
     this.c1 = c1;
     this.c2 = c2;
     this.c3 = c3;
  }

  public void Print()
  {
      c1.PrintMessageForClass1();
      c2.PrintMessageForClass2();
      c3.PrintMessageForClass3();
   }    
}
```

Then I use autofac as folllows

```
class ContainerConfig
{
   public static IContainer Configure()
   {
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       builder.RegisterType<Manage>().AsSelf();

       builder.RegisterType<Class1>().AsSelf();
       builder.RegisterType<Class2>().AsSelf();
       builder.RegisterType<Class3>().AsSelf();

      return builder.Build();
   }
}
```

In class Program:

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var container = ContainerConfigcs.Configure();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
         {
              var c = container.Resolve<Manage>();
              c.Print();
         }
     }
 }
```

For now, the output is:

```
This is class1
This is class2
This is class3
```

But I want to use an App.config where in the appsettings I can have a value like 1,2 or 3. For this example I set the value to 1

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="classType" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
```

I want to use this value from `App.config` to make `autofac` use only one of the three classes. For example, if the value is 1, I want to use the `Class1`, so on the console will be printed only
This is `class1`.
If I change the value to 2, I want `autofac` to use Class2, and so on.

How can I set `autofac` to receive the value in `AppConfig`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. TBH it does not makes a lot of sense right now. Do this classes have some common interface/base class?

Comment: @GuruStron I was unsure if an interface would help. In my example I don't have one

Comment: you need to introduce some common ground(like interface) and conditionally register based on your config and resolve interface, not concrete type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` from `System.Configuration` so you can extract the appConfig.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

You can access appSettings by the `classType` key, and then switch based on that. Now we have the classType value, we can decide exactly where we want to use it. I propose two options, in order of recommendation.

Autofac does not fully apply to your question. If you want the switching to occur **only** by Autofac, `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3` **must** implement the same interface.. say `IPrintStuff`. Then in your container config, you register **one** of the implementations 
 of `IPrintStuff`.

```
public static IContainer Configure()
{
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   var classType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["classType"].ToString();

   builder.RegisterType<Manage>().AsSelf();

    switch(classType)
    {
      case "1":
          builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IPrintStuff>();
      break;
      case "2":
          builder.RegisterType<Class2>().As<IPrintStuff>();
      break;
      case "3":
          builder.RegisterType<Class3>().As<IPrintStuff>();
      break;
    }

  return builder.Build();
}
```

*(And then `Manage` does not take in 3 classes anymore, it takes 1 parameter of type IPrintStuff)*

The other approach is to do it a bit higher up, in Manage.cs. It is still disadvantageous because you still have to new up the 3 objects, but only call one.

Manage.cs

```
public void Print()
{ 
    var classType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["classType"];
    switch(classType)
    {
      case "1":
          c1.PrintMessageForClass1();
      break;
      case "2":
          c2.PrintMessageForClass2();
      break;
      case "3":
          c3.PrintMessageForClass3();
      break;
    }
}
```